# How to bind JSON to a bean in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, struts2

Well, I want to make an Ajax call to an Struts 2 action, so I want to send a JSON with the specific `id` of an `Employee` bean from the client to the server.

The question is how it should be structured in order to set the `id` to the bean in the action.

I think that it should be something like:

```js
var employee = {Employee:{id:"someId"}}
```

is it ok?

this is the jQuery function that i'm using for

```js
 $('#select').change(function(){
     var id = $(this).val();
     var employee = {employee:{id:"someid"}};
     
     $.getJSON('ajax/getPhoto.action', employee , function(data){
        console.log(data);
     });         
    
 });
```

actually, after a debug I could see that the `Employee` bean is null in the `Action` at the moment of the call to the service.

Answer (score 0):

sending my json objects it has not been written directly as data: EmployeejsonObjects. As it expects the JSON object passed to it written as key value pair. So we made employee the key. And since we have json objects stored in a variable, we need to expand the json objects list using stringify(), otherwise it would be sent as a java script object.

```
$.getJSON('ajax/getPhoto.action', {employee: JSON.stringify(employee) } , function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` bean can't be `null` if it's instantiated and initialized the action bean. In this way the action bean should provide the getter for the `Employee` and a setter for `id` property.

Make sure the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) in included in the action config and your action class is not `ModelDriven`.

jQuery converts a JavaScript object like

> Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a **plain object**, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL.

---

Then you should check which parameters are passed to the action. You can do this if your action class implements `ParameterAware` or get parameters from the `ActionContext` like

```
Map parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

---

Here' you can populate parameters yourself instead of `params` interceptor as you have access to them or to configure the interceptor *correctly*, so it's able to do a job. Use `devMode` turned on when you debug the issue because it prints which parameter it's not able to set.